# confusion about mysql like search and = search

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I got this question when I use mysql search something. here is the detailed information.

say I got a table named `test` with a column named `content`. in a specific record, the `content` column holds:

```
["
/^\w{2,}/","
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$/","
/^[a-z0-9]+$/","
/^[a-z]\d+$/"]
```

there is a linefeed character in the end of the lines(last line excluded)
 so when I used the like syntax to search this record, I wrote a SQL like this

```
select * from test where `content` like 
'[\"\n/^\\\\w{2,}/\",\"\n/^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$/\",\"\n/^[a-z0-9]+$/\",\"\n/^[a-z]\\\\d+$/\"]'
```

and it returned the right result. but when I changed the `like` to `=` and this SQL statement didn't work, after I tried several times, I got this SQL statement that worked:

```
select * from test where `content` = 
'[\"\n/^\\w{2,}/\",\"\n/^[a-z][a-z0-9]+$/\",\"\n/^[a-z0-9]+$/\",\"\n/^[a-z]\\d+$/\"]'
```

it worked. so here is the question:
why on earth the `like` and `=` have different escape strategy? in the `like` statement I have to use `\\\\w`,`\\\\d` while in the `=` statement `\\w`,`\\d` just doing fine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MySQL LIKE` operator to select data *based on patterns*.

The `LIKE` operator is commonly used to select data based on patterns. Using the `LIKE` operator in the right way is essential to increase the query performance.

The `LIKE` operator allows you to select data from a table based on a specified pattern. Therefore, the `LIKE` operator is often used in the `WHERE` clause of the `SELECT` statement.

MySQL provides two wildcard characters for using with the `LIKE` operator, the percentage `%` and underscore `_`.

- The percentage (`%`) wildcard allows you to match any string of zero or more characters.
- The underscore (`_`) wildcard allows you to match any single character.

`Comparison operations` result in a value of 1 (`TRUE`), 0 (`FALSE`), or `NULL`. These operations work for both numbers and strings. Strings are automatically converted to numbers and numbers to strings as necessary.

The following relational comparison operators can be used to compare not only *scalar operands*, but row operands:

> =  >  <  >=  <=  <>  !=

*Note*: `=` is Equal operator and `LIKE` for Simple pattern matching

Comment: thanks for your answer @ Sinto. I understand it a little bit, I searched this in the mysql documentation but found nothing. so could you give a link or something about this in the mysql official documentation that I could refer to please?

Comment: Sure, here is one for you: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html And if my explanation helped you & if you think its helpful to other please mark it as an answer.

Comment: of course your answer is useful, your link too. I found this in the documentation: **Because MySQL uses C escape syntax in strings (for example, \n to represent a newline character), you must double any \ that you use in LIKE strings. For example, to search for \n, specify it as \\n. To search for \, specify it as \\\\; this is because the backslashes are stripped once by the parser and again when the pattern match is made, leaving a single backslash to be matched against.**